# SQL query to find count of values in two  columns

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite table where I have a list of messages:

```
to  | from
==========
9999  ME
9999  ME
ME    9999
ME    8888
```

The result of the query should be in the following format:

> number(number of records matching)

```
9999 (3)
8888 (1)
```

How can I write a query to give me this resultset? I'm working with Android.

Comment: How is Android relevant to the question? Can `to` and `from` be the same in one record? Would that count as 1 or 2?

Comment: Error messages in comments indicate sqlite, not postgresql. tag wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do something using this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

I guess something like this (didn't run it):

```
SELECT number, count(number) as `Count` FROM (
  SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN to = 'ME' THEN from
      ELSE to
    END AS number
    FROM table
  ) GROUP BY number;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT value, count(*)  
FROM ( 
   SELECT to as value
   FROM your_table

   UNION ALL

   SELECT "from" as value
   FROM your_table
) t
GROUP BY value
```

To filter out unwanted values for `to` and `from` use an approriate WHERE clause (ideally in the inner select to reduce the number of rows that need to be processed.

Comment: I changed field names and the query is almost ok; it returns
8888(1), 9999(3) *AND ME(4)*`

Comment: @WeContest: it's a column alias: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, and what should I put as "to" and "from"??

Comment: @WeContest: I have **no** idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I execute your query replacing _your_table_ with my table name, I get the following error: _#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to as value FROM table_name UNION ALL SELECT "from" as value ' at line 3_

Comment: @WeContest: maybe `value` is a reserved word in MySQL. Try using a different one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  value, sum (count) as count, from 
(
    select count(*) as count , "from" as value from your_table 
    group by "from"
   union all 
   select count(*) as count , "to" as value from your_table 
   group by "to" 
) t
group by t.value
```

Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name & @razvi!

Comment: The [] brackets are invalid SQL syntax. What are they supposed to do? And it should be `UNION ALL` otherwise the duplicates will be removed.

Comment: I guess they were put there so that they won't be considered as keywords (like the from field) ... maybe back-quotes instead of bracket will work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the [] were my way of escaping the reserved words (from) in the column names. That's actually valid in SQL server, I thought it might be valid in posgresql. ;) thanks for the union catch, will ammend my answer immediately.

Comment: @razvi exactly! thanks for the back quote tip, I can't do them from my cell but I will put double quotes at least for now. Will ammend my answer.

Comment: @Razvi: backticks are invalid in PostgreSQL as well (they are a non-standard behaviour of MySQL)

Comment: @Icarus: [] is not valid to quote reserved words in any DBMS (except SQL Server apparently)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the info. It seems that every DBMS does as it pleases. I've seen []," and back quotes for these things, I just try hard to avoid using any SQL reserved word when I name my tables and columns until some day a popular DBMS comes along and decides to make firstname, lastname, etc a reserved word and then I'll be in trouble for real.

Comment: @Icarus: all DBMS either use the standard double quotes or can be configured to accept them and I always recommend to configure them to be standard compliant (at least in that area)

Comment: This query returns: `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "from": syntax error: , while compiling: select  value, sum (count) as count, from ( select count(*) as count , "from_user" as value from tab_conversations group by "from_user" union all select count(*) as count , "to_user" as value from tab_conversations group by "to_user" ) t group by t.value`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to count the occurrences of numeric values this should work.

Use concatenation ("||") to form the output that you want.

```
SELECT to_from || ' (' || count(to_from) || ')' FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN to ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN to
      WHEN from ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN from
    END to_from
  FROM
    testing
) a
GROUP BY to_from
```

Results in

```
 ?column? 
----------
 9999 (3)
 8888 (1)
(2 rows)
```